# Three-level Meta-Analyses: correlation comparisons and correction for publication bias?

Tags: r, correlation, meta-analysis, metafor, publication-bias

I'm conducting a three-level meta-analysis on correlations using the {metafor} package on R.

I'm quite a newbie when it comes to three-level meta-analyses, so I have two doubts.

**1)** From each study, I collected effects sizes that indicate:

- correlations between variable A and variable B (A-B)
- correlations between variable A and variable C (A-C)

Simplified example of the database with the effect size:

```
> data

es.id   study.id   z      type
1       Study1     0.10   A-B
2       Study1     0.20   A-B
3       Study1     0.30   A-C
4       Study2     0.15   A-B
5       Study2     0.18   A-C
6       Study3     0.13   A-B
7       Study3     0.10   A-C
8       Study4     0.10   A-B
9       Study4     0.12   A-C
10      Study4     0.09   A-C
```

I planned to run two separate meta-analyses on this effect sizes (a meta-analysis for A-B correlations and another one for A-C correlations).
However, is it possible to compare the two pooled correlation coefficients, namely to say whether A-B correlations are stronger than A-C correlations in the same studies?

Intuitively, I'd run a three-level mixed-effect model of the entire pool of effect sizes (A-B and A-C correlations together), using the "type" of correlation (A-B vs. A-C) as a sort of within-study moderator.

Something like this:

```
rma.mv(yi, V, data, random = ~ 1 | study.id/es.id, method = "REML", mods = ~ type)
```

However, I'm not sure this is the best way to proceed and I could not find any study that approached the analysis as I planned to...

**2)** For my meta-analysis, I also planned to assess publication bias.
By looking at the best strategies to adopt with three-level meta-analyses, I decided to use Egg's Test with standard error as a moderator:

```
egger <- rma.mv(yi, V, mods = ~ se, random = ~1 | study.id/es.id, data)
egger
```

However, I failed in finding a reliable source concerning the possible correction strategies that can be applied to three-level meta-analyses.
I'd like to correct potential publication bias in my study, but most of the online resources describe strategies or procedures that are not easily applicable to *rma.mv* objects or complex analyses.
I would really appreciate it if you could point out some references on how to deal with publication bias on R with {metafor} or other packages.

Thank you everybody for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To compare the A-B and A-C correlations, you need to account for the dependency therein, not just by including random effects, but also for the dependency in the sampling errors. The `rcalc()` function (see [here](https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/rcalc.html)) helps with with computing those and constructing the proper `V` matrix. Note that you will need to include the B-C correlations in your dataset (since the covariance between $r_{AB}$ and $r_{AC}$ depends on $r_{BC}$). Also, instead of `random = ~ 1 | study.id/es.id`, you might want to use `random = ~ type | study.id, struct="UN"`.
2. Including the standard error as a predictor in your model (in addition to `type`)  would be the straightforward generalization of the 'regression test for funnel plot asymmetry'. See:

   Fernández-Castilla, B., Declercq, L., Jamshidi, L., Beretvas, S. N., Onghena, P. & Van den Noortgate, W. (2021). Detecting selection bias in meta-analyses with multiple outcomes: A simulation study. The Journal of Experimental Education, 89(1), 125-144. https://doi.org/10.1080/00220973.2019.1582470

   Rodgers, M. A. & Pustejovsky, J. E. (2021). Evaluating meta-analytic methods to detect selective reporting in the presence of dependent effect sizes. Psychological Methods, 26(2), 141-160. https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000300

Comment: Thank you, you really made my day!! For question (1), do you think that adding a random structure to the model as: ~ type | study.id/es. id (with effect sizes nested in studies) would be an extreme (and/or unuseful) complication to the random structure? As for (2), with "in addition to type" you mean something like this: rma.mv(yi, V, mods = ~ se + type, random = ~ type | study.id, data)?
Thank you!!

Comment: (1) `~ type | study.id/es. id` is not even possible even if you tried. It would also be overparameterized even if `rma.mv()` would allow this. (2) Yes. And note, you want to use `struct="UN"`, as otherwise it will assume struct="CS" which probably isn't appropriate here.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Your answers have been extremely useful!

Comment: I have read that if correlations come from mixed models, then the slop would be the best effect size indicator. But then, when making a meta analysis of such correlations, would you need to add the error of such slope estimates? The example does not add it.